# Create new pandas column based on conditions stated in a table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel-table called **rules_table** where each row represents a rule with a column representing the resulting category when that rule is true:

| Legs | Eyes | Color | Description | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 6 | NaN | Small | Spider |
| 4 | 2 | Black | Friendly | Dog |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | Tall | Human |

I.e. ignoring the NaN's, the table would create rules as shown in the pseudocode here:

```
If legs == 8 & Eyes == 6 & Description.contains("Small") then Category = "Spider"
If legs == 4 & Eyes == 2 & Color = "Black" & Description.contains("Friendly") then Category = "Dog"
If legs == 2 & Description.contains("Tall") then Category = "Human"
```

I also have another table called **data_table** with same format as the **rules_table** except it is missing the category column and *usually* does not contain NaN:

| Legs | Eyes | Color | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 6 | Brown | The creature is a small... |
| 13 | 2 | Orange | This is... |
| 4 | 2 | Black | This friendly creature... |
| 2 | 2 | White | The creature here is tall... |
| 1 | 11 | Yellow | The creature here is... |

**My goal** is to add the category of the **rules_table** to the **data_table** whenever the rule applies, such that executing the code:

```
complete_table = my_function(rules_table, data_table)
```

Yields the **complete_table**:

| Legs | Eyes | Color | Description | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 6 | Brown | The creature is a small... | Spider |
| 13 | 2 | Orange | This is... | NaN |
| 4 | 2 | Black | This friendly creature... | Dog |
| 2 | 2 | White | The creature here is tall... | Human |
| 1 | 11 | Yellow | The creature here is... | NaN |

I am currently loading both tables as pandas dataframes, but am open to all options, note that I have millions of rows so efficiency is important to consider (but not critical).

**I have tried two approaches**

*Approach 1:*
I have tried to join/merge the tables and make a work-around function for executing the "description.contains" part of the rule. However, the NaN's are making it tricky for me, and I am not sure how I should work around that.

*Approach 2:*
I have tried iterating over each row of the rules_table, and then create a list of filters and a list of desired values which I then use together with np.select. However, I cannot figure out how to programatically construct executable code, and therefore end up with strings I cannot use as intended.

**Do you have a suggestion for how I may proceed here? I am getting a bit stuck**

I can share code if you want, but I am getting stuck on a more fundamental level than just syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with SQL, this problem would have easily solved with its flexible `JOIN` statements. In MS SQL Server, you can solve your problem like this:

```sql
FROM      data_table   d 
LEFT JOIN rules_table  r   ON (d.Legs  = r.Legs)
                          AND (d.Eyes  = r.Eyes  OR r.Eyes  IS NULL)
                          AND (d.Color = r.Color OR r.Color IS NULL)
                          AND (CHARINDEX(r.Description, d.Description) != 0)
```

Unfortunately, pandas's joins (as implemented by `pd.join` and `pd.merge`) are no where as flexible. One way to overcome this is to first perform a cross join and then filter the intermediary result:

```py
def my_function(rules_table, data_table):
    # Make a unique number for each row
    # To prevent changing the original data_table, we make a new copy
    new_data_table = data_table.assign(RowNumber=range(len(data_table)))

    # Join every row in new_data_table to every row in rules_table
    # We will filter for the matches later
    tmp = new_data_table.merge(rules_table, how='cross', suffixes=('', '_rules'))

    # Filter for the matches
    match = (
        ( tmp['Legs']  == tmp['Legs_rules'] ) &
        ((tmp['Eyes']  == tmp['Eyes_rules'] ) | tmp['Eyes_rules'].isna()) &
        ((tmp['Color'] == tmp['Color_rules']) | tmp['Color_rules'].isna()) &
        tmp.apply(lambda row: row['Description_rules'].lower() in row['Description'].lower(), axis=1)
    )

    # Perform another left join to produce final result
    result = new_data_table.merge(tmp.loc[match, ['RowNumber', 'Category']], how='left', on='RowNumber')
    return result.drop(columns='RowNumber')
```

Comment: Follow-up question: For both SQL and Python, how would you handle the case where  the description column is NaN? For instance, if you remove the description "Tall" from the human row of the rules_table, the category fails to apply. 

PS: Accepted this as the answer as you completely nailed exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: One additional question: You seem to not include the "Description" part in SQL - is this because SQL is not able to join on a "contains" basis, or does this functionality also exist here? Reason I am asking is I have the opportunity to potentially do this in SQL, but do not currently know SQL.

Comment: Sorry there was a bug in the SQL code. The last line should have read `Description` but I wrote `Category` instead. Fixed. The "contains" condition is handled by `CHARINDEX(...) != 0`. The SQL is in Microsoft SQL Server language. It may not work with other variants of SQL